NextJS migrate from App Router 14 to 15. Property 'params' is missing in type 'Context' but required in type 'RouteContext'
I have just migrated from NextJS 14 to 15 using the app router method. On Windows.
I am having an issue with one of my static routes. It is not dynamic route, but is gettings errors as if it was.
interface Context {
  data: object;
  params: any;
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, context: Context) {
  const testBody = await request.json();
....function continues on....
......

When I run: npm run dev it works fine, but when I build with : npm run build it fails to pass linting and checking validity of types. And I get the following error:
PS C:\Users\SJ\Desktop\nextjsProject> npm run build

> build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 15.0.3
   - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ..Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/api/myRoute/route.ts:166:7
Type error: Type '{ __tag__: "POST"; __param_position__: "second"; __param_type__: Context; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'ParamCheck<RouteContext>'.
  Types of property '__param_type__' are incompatible.
    Property 'params' is missing in type 'Context' but required in type 'RouteContext'.

  164 |     Diff<
  165 |       ParamCheck<aRouteContext>,
> 166 |       {
      |       ^
  167 |         __tag__: 'POST'
  168 |         __param_position__: 'second'
  169 |         __param_type__: SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'POST'>>

What I have Tried:

Removing the context parameter from the POST method
Changing the Interface Context params to a type of Promise<string> and Promise<any>
Changing the Interface Context to type Context
instead of passing in context : Context I pass in context: {params: Promise<any>}
Read the NextJS Migrate documentation and implemented some of their suggestions and nothing works.

Please help!

Replace context: Context with { params }: { params: Promise<{ id: string }> }
Then, retrieve the value using:
const id = (await params).id

This fixed it for me, Thanks!

Cool! Sure thing.

type Params = Promise<{req:Request}>
export async function POST(req: Request, segmentData: { params: Params }) {

let reqdata = await req.json();

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
